# Combine/Mix two lists of words

Tags: php, arrays

I have two lists of words in two arrays

first array

> Array
>   (
>     [0] => make
>     [1] => break
>     [2] => buy
>   )

second array

> Array
>   (
>     [0] => home
>     [1] => car
>     [2] => bike
>   )

and I want to display all possible combinations but make sure the first array is always the first word and 2nd array is always the second word:

The above two arrays should display the following list:

> make home
>   make car
>   make bike
>   break home
>   break car
>   break bike
>   buy home
>   buy car
>   buy bike

Thank you in advance.

Hi Saikios,
thanks for your reply.

This is what I have which seems very similar to what you have posted:

```
    $list1 = array("make","break","buy");
$list2 = array("home","car","bike");

for($a=0; $a<3; $a++){
    for($b=0; $b<3; $b++){
        echo($list1[$a].$list2[$b]);
        echo("<br />");
    }
}
```

Just was wondering if there is a better way. Both of my lists have about 200 words.

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried, if anything. This sounds like homework.

Comment: Not really just for 2 arrays is the best way around.
you can read here about big o http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf look for Nested loops ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a correct answer I would need to know what you are trying or how,

but a solution for that problem is as simple as

```
<?php

$array1 = array("make", "break", "buy");
$array2 = array("home", "car", "bike");

foreach ($array1 as $i => $value) {
    foreach ($array2 as $j => $value2) {
        echo $value.' '.$value2.'<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($firstarray as $f)
{
    foreach($secondarray as $s)
    {
    echo $f.' '.$s;
    }
}
```

To make sure the first array is always the first word we use it as the primary loop. In essence we are iterating through each item and for each item we find in the array we are then looping through the second array so it creates all the word combinations for each item in the first array.

This example is more efficient that the previously chosen answer since pulling the array key out of each item is not needed and therefore not the most efficient answer to the question.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to include an explanation of what it does, and why this is the best method for solving the problem. Code-only answers are of limited use, and may be deleted.

Comment: i clearly have an explanation